# Isolating a voice

Tags: voice

I have a recording of someone talking while driving. There is a lot of road noise that I cannot get around. I want to isolate the voice from the road noise. I have tried using Audacity but the frequencies of the voice and road noise are too close. I haven't had any luck. Any suggestions to help me isolate a voice from a noisy car ride.

Comment: [Izotope RX](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/audio-repair/rx/) might be able to get rid of a fair bit of it, but it's not cheap, really not cheap.

Comment: If you have the option of re-recording this and getting the mic closer to the source that might be an easier option in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Selective eq-ing is the option for this kind of restauration.

Using an spectral imaging software/plugin can be useful to visually see loudest sounds and be able to separate that from ambient noise. Software that would enable spectral editing like above mentioned Izotope's RX would make it easier.

[image]

Restoration requires patience and even so - if applicable - recording another take with properly set microphones will generally yield better results